# xcode name change causing iphone simulator to crash

Tags: xcode, project, rename

Today I changed my Xcode project and now when I build and run the app it crashes when clicking anything in the app. If anyone could please help out I would really appreciate it, I spent so much time working on this project and had just finished it. I decided to change the name last minute and now I got myself in a pickle.

Thanks for all the help everyone but i guess I'm going to try and re work a new project all over again. :(

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. You have posted the same question three times now. Just post once. You can always update your question with more details.

Comment: k sorry about that. Im looking for answer to my problem everywhere and no solution anywhere. I really do hope I have not wasted all my time on this project. all help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the Simulator and do a Product - Clean in Xcode.

Renaming the project changes your bundle identifier. It's often recommend as a best practice to not use the default bundle identifier but to just explicitly set it com.apple.mail

After further investigation it looks like the rename is not the issue. You need to set and exception breakpoint to see what is going on.

[image]

[image]

Now run it with the debugger attached and make it crash.

Comment: Just tried that but didnt work :/

Comment: quit xcode and the simulator and if that does not work reboot.

Comment: crashed again when clicking anything in the app

Comment: the simulator crashes or your app crashes?

Comment: the application, it never happened until after i had changed the name.

Comment: What is listed in the log. Generally crashes like that are from broken connections in your storyboard.

Comment: thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: k just added it to the question. I really hope i didnt waste all my time making this project due to changing the name.

Comment: did you enable snapshots when you renamed the project? If so then you can go to File - Restore Snapshot ... and you will be back to before the rename. You should be using source control git is your fiend

Comment: yes i remember doing so

Comment: good go to the menu File - Restore Snapshot

Comment: that was the error i got

Comment: do a clean and reset the simulator

Comment: its still crashes as soon as i click on anything in the app

Comment: then it was not the rename that is the problem see updated answer

Comment: k I followed the instruction and it crashed again.

Comment: it should crash, you have not fixed anything yet. The break point should pause the debugger in the code that is calling initFileURLWithPath.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer just for ASL***

See the exception being thrown:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
    reason: ' -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

Set a breakpoint at your initFileURLWithPath method and look at it in the Xcode debugger.  I bet you'll catch the path being something you weren't expecting it to be.

***Original Answer:***

As you've discovered, changing the name of your project can indeed be really tricky and if you don't change it properly, catastrophic things can happen.

Do you have a Time Machine backup of your project?  If so, you can easily get back to last night's version of your project before you attempted to do the name change.

Then, changing the name of your app can be as simple as changing the "Bundle display name" in the info.plist file:

[image: Change Bundle Display Name]

This is the lightweight, easy way to do it.

And yes, it doesn't change the underlying project name, but it does change the display name and for your customers, that's all that really matters.

2)

Now, to change the underlying project name, you need to have some time and patience.

I start by typing in the new name for the Xcodeproject file, like this:

[image: Change Project Name]

Which brings up this sheet:

[image: Change Name Sheet]

Then look at your target settings to make sure the old name doesn't exist anymore:

[image: Look at Settings]

And after all that's done, you might want to change the name of your scheme (via the Xcode scheme editor), since the old name is probably still there as well.

Comment: no i dont have one :(

Comment: see if you can change the name of your app back to the *old* name and get it just to compile and work again

Comment: Tried changing it back and didnt work.